# How save custom header?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a custom header like this:

```
header($_SERVER['Example']);
```

but when I do: `var_dump($_SERVER);` there is no `Example` header. I want also add some content to the header. How I can achieve that?

Comment: And this data must be available for all users ?

Comment: The fact you need to do this is disturbing :S

Comment: @Flosculus why is disturbing?

Comment: @Sandokan Because with the exception of `$_SESSION`, all super globals should be read only.  There is little telling how writing to `$_SERVER` will cascade through your application later on.

Comment: @Flosculus 
It's a good thing save the id of who use actually the API in $_SERVER? I want avoid the use of the session or cookie.

Comment: Just for clarity, are you expecting the value to persist in `$_SERVER` between requests?

Comment: @Flosculus nope, I want destroy the value, I need to save somewhere (in this case in the $_SERVER) the information of the user, this will be destroyed when the execution come to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER` is just an array, so why not

```
$_SERVER['Example'] = 'hello';
var_dump( $_SERVER );
```

Comment: It's a good thing save the id of who use actually the API in `$_SERVER`? I want avoid the use of the session or cookie.

Comment: Well this will be destroyed when the script finishes executing. If you want to pass content across multiple communications you need either session data, cookies, or passing header content back and forth `header('Example: value');` - give us more information maybe we can better understand your needs

Comment: No I need to destroy this value.. I need it only for a transaction that start and finish in some seconds... this `$_SERVER['example']` it's usefull for me for write who it's performing the trace...